# Python: how to use MultiProcessing while doing bubble sort combine merge sort?

Tags: python, sorting, multiprocessing, queue, pool

This is a part of the file.
Problem: Sorting a given list of integers. cut into k chunk, each using bubble sort, and merge all of them. (Using MultiProcessing)

I'm struggling with the syntax of MultiProcessing. (sorting is done perfectly)
I can't get the code below work out...
How to store the list right into the queue? QQ

```
def sort_chunk_multi(q, chunk):
    q.put(bubble_sort(chunk))

def sort_and_merge_multi(arr, k):
    # split arr into k chunks
    n = len(arr)
    chunk_size = n // k
    chunks = [arr[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, n, chunk_size)]
    # handle case where n % k != 0
    if len(chunks) > k:
        last_chunk = chunks.pop()
        chunks[-1] += last_chunk
    # bubble sort each chunk in parallel
    with multiprocessing.Pool(k) as pool:
        results = []
        for chunk in chunks:
            result = pool.apply_async(
                sort_chunk_multi, args=(multiprocessing.Manager().Queue(), chunk))
            results.append(result)
        sorted_chunks = [result.get() for result in results]
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    # merge sorted chunks in parallel
    with multiprocessing.Pool(k-1) as pool:
        while len(sorted_chunks) > 1:
            results = []
            for i in range(0, len(sorted_chunks), 2):
                left = sorted_chunks[i]
                if i+1 < len(sorted_chunks):
                    right = sorted_chunks[i+1]
                else:
                    right = []
                result = pool.apply_async(merge, args=(left, right))
                results.append(result)
            sorted_chunks = [result.get() for result in results]
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    return sorted_chunks[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = sort_and_merge_multi(numbers, k)
```

result.get()

RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance

Comment: I don't think you need a `Queue` here at all. You should be able to just return `bubble_sort(chunk)`.